# Can't import custom nodeset in node opc ua Server

Tags: node.js, xml, opc-ua, node-opcua

I am a newbie to OpcUa and I am working with node opcua stack.

I created an information model using SIOME.

I am now trying to import it in the server.

Here it is the code:

```
const opcua = require("node-opcua");

var nodeset_filename1 ="Opc.Ua.Di.NodeSet2.xml";
var nodeset_filename2 ="custom.NodeSet2.xml" //this one is getting me error


var server_options = {
    nodeset_filename : [opcua.nodesets.standard_nodeset_file ,nodeset_filename1 , nodeset_filename2],
    port : xxxx,
    resourcePath:"/UA/Server"
}

const server = new opcua.OPCUAServer(server_options);

function post_initialize() {
    console.log("initialized");
    server.start(function() {
        console.log("Server is now listening ... ( press CTRL+C to stop)");
        console.log("port ", server.endpoints[0].port);
    });
}
server.initialize(post_initialize);
```

Here it is the error I get:

```
C:\path\node_modules\node-opcua-address-space\dist\source\loader\load_nodeset2.js:764
                        this.bodyXML = this._cloneFragment.value;
```

I tried with standard models from OpcUa and it seems to work.

Do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you please share your custom.NodeSet2.xml?
2. Which tool did you use to create this custom.NodeSet2.xml? Did you use [UA-ModelCompiler](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-ModelCompiler%20?)
3. I checked [load_nodeset2.js](http://node-opcua.github.io/api_doc/0.2.0/files/packages_node-opcua-address-space_src_loader_load_nodeset2.js.html) file and line 764 is empty. There might be some parsing issue with the custom xml file.